# Free Pascal Compiler - Fatal: Syntax error, "OF" expected but "[" found ...?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have defined this procedure where

```
Player
```

is a user-defined record.Here is the procedure:

```
procedure print_scores(players : array[1..2] of Player);
begin
    writeln;
    writeln(' Player 1 (', players[1].player_name.firstname, ' ',players[1].player_name.lastname, ') |=| ', players[1].score);
    writeln(' Player 2 (', players[2].player_name.firstname, ' ',players[2].player_name.lastname, ') |=| ', players[2].score);
    writeln;
end;
```

But I get this error:

> main.pas(9,39) Fatal: Syntax error, "OF" expected but "[" found

I have checked and the line

```
procedure print_scores(players : array[1..2] of Player);
```

is line # 9.

Comment: ...and 39 is a character position in the line 9 of the opening bracket `[` in `array[1..2]`.

Comment: @CiaPan yeah :) . But I didn't know why I got the error. Now I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define the array type in the procedure argument list. It must be defined separately.

```
type
  TPlayers = array[1..2] of TPlayer;
```

The the procedure is:

```
procedure print_scores(const Players: TPlayers);
```

Comment: Not in FreePascal, indeed, but in some other Pascals, you can, e.g. [ISO Pascal](http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#6.6.1%20Procedure-declarations) (example 1).

Comment: Those are conforming arrays and those are not part of the base ISO Pascal level (0),